# Reading data from datagridview and saving into list

Tags: c#, winforms, list, for-loop, datagridview

I have a C# program that stores some data in a datagridview called DGV. 
DGV has 6 columns and has the following structure:

Column1: SALES_US

Column2: QUANTITY_US

Column3: SALES_EU

Column4: QUANTITY_EU

Column5: SALES_AS

Column6: QUANTITY_AS

The programs fills the columns labelled as "SALES" (e.g. columns 1-3-5) with the name of some items. Then in the columns labelled as "QUANTITY" (e.g. columns 2-4-6) the user input some numbers only if some of the item has been sold. 
E.g. if in row 1 I have the item A, in cell[1, 0] (so row 0, column 1, supposing that rows/columns are indexed starting from 0) I can put 1000 if 1000 items A have been sold in US, and so on.

So, after user input, the DGV will have in column 1-3-5 (again, supposing that index starts at 0) some numbers but it is also possible that some cells are empty.

So I need to loop through the columns where the user has input the quantities and store the quantities in a list (in my example below I have created a list of string, called "myKeys").

Is there a quick/efficient way of doing this? Please consider that I am not super expert and so far I have only found the following (which works but seems very slow).

```
class organizer
{
    public List<string> organize(DataGridView DGV, DataGridView DGV2, 
        DataGridView DGV3)
    {

    List<string> myKeys = new List<string>(); //This is the list of quantities

    // the cells of DGV are accessible using [col, row] coordinates

        for (int counterRows = 0; counterRows < countRows; counterRows++)
        {
            try // look for data in the second column
            {
                test = DGV[1, counterRows].Value.ToString(); // if the cells is empty the string conversion is not possible and no info will be stored
                myKeys.Add(DGV[1, counterRows].Value.ToString());
            }
            catch{}

            try // look for data in the fourth column
            {
                test = DGV[3, counterRows].Value.ToString(); // if the cells is empty the string conversion is not possible and no info will be stored
                myKeys.Add(DGV[3, counterRows].Value.ToString());
            }
            catch{}            

            try // look for data in the sixth column
            {
                test = DGV[5, counterRows].Value.ToString(); // if the cells is empty the string conversion is not possible and no info will be stored
                myKeys.Add(DGV[5, counterRows].Value.ToString());
            }
            catch{}
         }

    // here the same for-loop is repeated to add the quantities to the list reading from the other datagridviews. 

    return myKeys;

    }
}
```

In this case I loop through the cells with a for loop and use the try-catch to see if the value can be converted to string. If the cell is empty, the ".ToString()" will fail and the following line that add the cell value in the list "myKeys" is not executed. 
But I need to specify directly that I first work on column 1, the 3 and finally 5.

Apart from the (probably) useless code duplication, the code seems to run quite slow for such a small datagridview (I have less than 50 rows). I need to do this on other datagridviews, applying same logic.

Your suggestion about better way to deal with the problem are very appreciated.

Comment: what event are  you doing this in..? please show full method signature also you can get a the selected row by easily doing a foreach loop as well are you wanting to read all the rows or just a selected row...

Comment: I added more info about the code. It is a class where I have just one method that has the datagridviews as input and is expected to return a list of string containing the quantities.

Comment: But this way I still need to write/repeat the same code for each column name?

Comment: you write the column names that you want within the foreach loop are you familiar with `foreach loop` it loops over a `Collection` for example do this 
open up Google and type the following `C# stackoverflow foreach(DataGridviewRow` and you will see many working examples also I would totally refactor / re-think your current solution, you are trying to mix and match thing about creating custom classes that represent your table layouts and just add / create new instances of your class that you can add to a List<SomeClass> does this make sense..?

Comment: Error 1 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' because 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: if you decide to keep your current structure then you need to a add some additional `if conditional checks` inside that loop and I would look up how to use `ternary` `?`

Comment: `DataGridViewRow` not `DataGridView`

Comment: The error is because I have to use     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV.Rows){}

Comment: `Duh` I told you that originally.. good luck I don't have time to hold you hand..

Comment: No but the problem was in DGV.Rows

Comment: you should know the rows your want based on the column names or index value ..i would use the column names personally for example you would want to do a foreah loop like the following `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV.Rows){}` from there you could do myKeys.Add(DGV["columnname].Value or .Value.ToString()
yes I know.. you needed to use the `.Rows` at the end

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll try to rewrite with the foreach and see if it's faster.

Comment: I'm trying now with the foreach, as you suggested. I also removed the try-catch and replaced with just an if statement to add the cell value only if it is !=null. It is now much faster... don't know if the problem was the for loop or the try-catch. Any idea?